# Keeping update timestamps in sync in Yii

Tags: php, timestamp, yii, relationship

I have a `Project` model and a `Comment` model that are connected with `has many relationship`( project -> comment ).

Im currently using [CTimestampBehavior](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CTimestampBehavior) to keep the `created and updated fields in sync` but i want the project model change update timestamp when a comment is added, changed or deleted. I got several of cases like this in my project and I would just like to know the best way to go about all of this.

Can I use `AfterSave()` on each model and tell it to update its parent? That would trigger a chain when a comment is updated that would update all the way to the top. Should I do it this way or does Yii have support for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge Yii does not have support for this feature. Not sure how that should be implemented in the framework either.

Can't really see any negative sides with this, and I'd definitely look into the same approach myself.

Comment: I'll go with that solution. Thanks for the input